Python script incorrectly assigns numbering to amino acids in interaction count output file
I've encountered an issue with a Python script designed to process input files containing protein-protein interaction data. The script aims to generate an output file with counts of different types of interactions between pairs of amino acids. However, it seems to be incorrectly assigning numbering to amino acids in the output file.
I'm working on analyzing protein-protein interaction data. The input files provided contain lines representing various types of interactions between pairs of amino acids, labeled with identifiers such as "sb", "pc", and "ps". Each line consists of the interaction label followed by the names of two amino acids involved in the interaction.
This is a subset of my data:
vdw PHE-287 VAL-19
vdw ILE-16 VAL-19
vdw ILE-16 VAL-19
vdw ILE-16 VAL-19
vdw ILE-16 VAL-19
vdw LEU-17 VAL-19
vdw ARG-290 VAL-19
vdw LEU-17 VAL-19
vdw VAL-19 VAL-21
vdw VAL-19 VAL-21
vdw ILE-23 VAL-19
vdw PHE-22 VAL-19
vdw PHE-22 VAL-19
vdw PHE-22 VAL-19
vdw ILE-23 VAL-19
vdw ILE-23 VAL-19
hbbb SER-20 VAL-19
hbbb TRP-18 VAL-19
hbbb PHE-22 VAL-19
hbbb VAL-19 VAL-21
hbbb ILE-23 VAL-19
hbbb LEU-17 VAL-19
hbbb TRP-18 VAL-19
hbbb ILE-16 VAL-19
hbbb SER-20 VAL-19

Here's the raw data:
Raw Data
After running the Python script provided below to process the input files and generate output files with interaction counts, I noticed that the numbering of amino acids in the output file does not match the original input data. For example, many other amino acids like "LEU" is assigned the number "19" in the output file, whereas it should be only "VAL".
import os
import collections

interactions = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)

interaction_kinds = ["sb", "pc", "ps", "vdw", "hbbb", "hbsb", "hbss"]

# Function to process a single input file
def process_file(input_file):
    with open(input_file, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip().split()
            if len(line) == 3:
                pair = frozenset(line[1:])
                interactions[pair][line[0]] += 1

# Function to generate output file name based on input file name
def generate_output_file_name(input_file):
    return input_file.replace("_h_contacts_count.txt", "_interaction_count.tsv")

# Get the current working directory
input_directory = os.getcwd()

# Process all input files in the current working directory
for filename in os.listdir(input_directory):
    if filename.endswith("_h_contacts_count.txt"):
        input_file = os.path.join(input_directory, filename)
        process_file(input_file)
        output_file_name = generate_output_file_name(input_file)
        with open(output_file_name, "w") as output_file:
            for pair, counts in interactions.items():
                r1, r2 = list(pair)  # Convert frozenset back to list
                counts = [counts.get(x, 0) for x in interaction_kinds]
                print(*counts, r1, r2, sep="\t", file=output_file)

        # Apply sed-like functionality to replace '-' with ' ' in the output file
        with open(output_file_name, "r+") as output_file:
            content = output_file.read()
            output_file.seek(0)
            output_file.write(content.replace('-', ' '))

The output I received:
0   0   0   2   1   0   0   LEU 19  LYS 15
0   0   0   5   1   0   0   LEU 19  LEU 16
0   0   0   2   0   0   0   LEU 265 LEU 19
0   0   0   2   1   0   0   GLU 21  LEU 19
0   0   0   0   2   0   0   LEU 19  THR 18


While also providing the correct rows like:
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   VAL 19  PHE 287
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   VAL 19  ARG 290
0   0   0   3   1   0   0   VAL 19  ILE 23
0   0   0   3   1   0   0   VAL 19  PHE 22
0   0   0   0   2   0   0   VAL 19  TRP 18


What could be causing the incorrect assignment of numbering to amino acids in the output file?
How can I modify the script to ensure that the numbering of amino acids in the output file matches the input data?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Your code works fine, There's no LEU 19 in the output file. Make sure you don't have any other data files in the folder.
